# Hector API - Create Column Family - key validation class

Tags: api, cassandra, hector

Hey guys I am trying to load a schema into a Cassandra 0.8.2 database via Hector.

I want to add a column family (in a particular keyspace) & specify its name, comparator type, key validation class, and default validation class via Hector.

I've looked through the documentation here:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/hector/api/factory/HFactory.java

for the function that to do this, but it seems I must have the Column Family already created (via the Cassandra CLI) to specify the default validation class, & key validation class when creating the Column Family via the CLI. Am I correct in this assumption? Am I missing any methods? Is it possible to alter the default validation class & key validation class of a Cassandra column family via Hector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with hector.  There is an example in [CassandraClusterTest](https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/hector-0.8.0-2/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/service/CassandraClusterTest.java#L153) where you can see new column families being created with the validation class set.  There are methods on BasicColumnFamilyDefinition to set the key validation class and comparator as well.